# Php search query with range filter

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do a search query, but not sure how to put everything together. I am having problem with the range filter part.

What i am trying to achieve:
A search form that 
1.) If field A,B(not empty) then put in the search query

2.) search through price column with (price lower range, price higher range)
include the results if it matches Field A,B(if it is not empty) and price(if it is in range).
(if search Fields A, B are empty then display all results that exist between range).

Thanks for your time.

The codes that i have now.

```
    <?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);
    session_start();
    include 'connect.php';
    if($_POST) 
    {
    $A = ($_POST['A']);
    $B = ($_POST['B']);
    $C = ($_POST['C']);
    $pricelow = ($_POST['pricelow']);
    $pricehigh = ($_POST['pricehigh']);
    $sql = array();
    if (!empty($A)) {
        $sql[] = "A='$A'";
    }
    if (!empty($B)) {
        $sql[] = "B='$B'";
    }
    if (!empty($C)) {
        $sql[] = "C='$C'";
    }
    if (!empty($price)) {
    for($i = pricelow; $i<pricehigh; $i++){
        $price = $i;
    }
    $sql[] = "price='$price'";
    $sql = implode(' AND ', $sql);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Listing" . (!empty($sql)? " WHERE " . $sql: '');
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $output = array();
    // fetch your results
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) )
    {
        // add result row to your output's next index
        $output[] = $row;
    }
    // echo the json encoded object
    echo json_encode( $output ); 
    }
    ?>
```

Edit:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Listing" . (!empty($sql)? " WHERE " . $sql: '') . ("AND" 'price' BETWEEN  "$pricelow" AND "$pricehigh");
```

Edit:

```
if (!empty($pricelow) || !empty($pricehigh)) {


        $sql[] =  $pricehigh>= 'price' and  'price'>=$pricelow ;

}
$sql = array();


$sql = implode(' AND ', $sql);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Listing" . (!empty($sql)? " WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $sql): '');
```

Comment: Look up the "between" SQL statement.

Comment: I tried it but i cant seem to get it right. I put my attempt in the edit above

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);


    session_start();

    include 'connect.php';

    if($_POST) 
    {

    $A = ($_POST['A']);
    $B = ($_POST['B']);
     $C = ($_POST['C']);
     $pricelow = ($_POST['pricelow']);
 $pricehigh = ($_POST['pricehigh']);

     $query = "SELECT * FROM Listing WHERE ";
     $flag = 0;

    if (!empty($A)) {
        $query .= $flag==0?" A='$A' ":" AND A = '$A'";
        $flag = 1;
    }
    if (!empty($B)) {
        $query .= $flag==0?" B = '$B' ":" AND B = '$B'";
        $flag = 1;    
    }
    if (!empty($C)) {
        $query .= $flag==0?" C='$C' ":" AND C= '$C'";
        $flag = 1;
    }

    if ($flag == 0) {
        $query .= " price > $pricelow AND price > $pricehigh"
    }


    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

            $output = array();

    // fetch your results
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) )
    {
        // add result row to your output's next index
        $output[] = $row;
    }

    //your rest of the code
>?
```

I can't test it so, try and report the result!

Comment: I just tested it, but it returned nothing

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an array of conditions and later you try to use that array as a string. This will not work, as the generated query is invalid. Take a look [here](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.implode.php), `implode` is a function which implodes an `array` using a separator. If you use `" AND "` as separator, then you will get the string you have desired. So, instead of:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Listing" . (!empty($sql)? " WHERE " . $sql: '');
```

do the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Listing" . (!empty($sql)? " WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $sql): '');
```

and your problem should be solved.

EDIT:

I have read your edit and I mean this code in particular:

```
if (!empty($pricelow) || !empty($pricehigh)) {


        $sql[] =  $pricehigh>= 'price' and  'price'>=$pricelow ;

}
$sql = array();


$sql = implode(' AND ', $sql);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Listing" . (!empty($sql)? " WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $sql): '');
```

After you build your array you are initializing it again, thus you lose all information you have processed earlier. Then you implode it twice, which is not needed. Try this way:

```
if (!empty($pricelow) || !empty($pricehigh)) {


        $sql[] =  $pricehigh>= 'price' and  'price'>=$pricelow ;

}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Listing" . (!empty($sql)? " WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $sql): '');
```

Comment: I tried it but i have Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in

Comment: I moved the $sql = array(); to just before the query, now it displays results, but it displays every result even when its outside the range.

Comment: Yes, because your array is empty then. You need to fill your array with values before you implode it.

Comment: Not very sure if i understand what you mean, because this php file is getting data from my app, and it searches thru the database with no problem with the text, but it does not filter the range